# swift - Writing binary directly, like Python

Tags: python, ios, swift3, hex

In Python, you can write in hex directly like this; `\x00\x01\x02`. For a project of mine, I need to be able to do the same or similar in Swift 3; I'm basically communicating over a websocket, and I have to send byte strings with values such as 0x01 or 0x13, values that do not have a printing character equivalent.

The format of the commands would be represented in Python like this; `\x25\x00\x00\x01\x00`, where individual bytes are not only commands but parameters. For this reason I need the ability to append like strings without one byte affecting another.

I've been looking around, and I once found a Swift class called Byte(), however for the life of me I can't figure out how to use it. Also, a lot of the tutorials I've seen are based on either receiving byte data or converting strings to binary, something I can't do.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:** On request, this is an example of what I'm trying to do;

*In Python:* (this works)

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost','8080'))

payload = b'\x25\x00\x00\x01\x00'

sock.send(payload)
resp = sock.recv(100)
print resp
```

*In Swift:* (I need to fill in the nil)

```
import UIKit
import Starscream

class ViewController: UIViewController, WebSocketDelegate{
    var socket: WebSocket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "localhost:8080")!)

    // ... viewDidLoad, didReceiveMemoryWarning, and
    // Starscream functions like websocketDidConnect

    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: UIButton){
        var payload = nil //I need to write payload in Python above here
        socket.write(payload)
    }
}
```

Comment: show us some code example which reflecting your trouble

Comment: I am pretty sure you can write c level code. Not certain about binary.

Comment: @user3441734 Updated with code snippets.

Comment: where is WebSocket from? what is the signature of its .send() function?

Comment: if you are talking about https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/blob/master/Source/WebSocket.swift there is no send function defined.

Comment: @user3441734 I already have Starscream working in a different project. I'm not looking for Starscream help, I'm looking for help writing binary to send _through_ Starscream; basically, I need to fill var payload with a stream of hex numbers.

Comment: without knowing how send function is declared, there is no chance to help you, sorry. at least give us some information about your payload type

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. It's actually the write function, I just threw up some code to illustrate my problem. write sends a String. I've edited accordingly.@user3441734

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Starscream

```
/**
     Write binary data to the websocket. This sends it as a binary frame.
     If you supply a non-nil completion block, I will perform it when the write completes.
     - parameter data:       The data to write.
     - parameter completion: The (optional) completion handler.
     */
    open func write(data: Data, completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {
        guard isConnected else { return }
        dequeueWrite(data, code: .binaryFrame, writeCompletion: completion)
    }
```

based on that, you have to

```
let data = Data(bytes: [UInt8(25),0,1,2,0,255,0xAB]) // create data b'\x25\x00\x01\x02\x00\xFF\xAB'
sock.write(data: data)
```